# Flask: read scalaris file from request

Tags: python, flask, insomnia

when I picked the flask the json file I used this line for it:
data = request.get_json ()
is it possible, and if so how, how to load uploaded files in request? Eg .sclaris .xml .odt files etc.
[image]

I send this type of file by Insomnia

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `request.files.get('filename')`